# how to pass automatic url to http protocol in Node js

Tags: node.js

In my file there is an index.html that contains the links, there is a display.html to render the images, a server.js and a folder containing the images.
When I click on the link, I want to open the display.html, but render a different image for each link. But I don't want to keep writing requests for each link.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Requisições</title>
    <script src="funcoes.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">
    <h1 id="h1" style="font-size: 30px; color: #000;">Links</h1>
    <a href="/page/1">link 1</a>
    <a href="/page/2">link 2</a>
    <a href="/page/3">link 3</a>
    <a href="/page/4">link 4</a>
    <a href="/page/5">link 5</a>
</body>
</html>
```

`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Display</title>
</head>
<body style="align-items: center; text-align: center;">
    <div style="background-color: darkkhaki; width: 500px; height: 300px;">
        <p>img</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('.'))

const fetch = require('node-fetch')

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html')
})

app.get('/page/:1',(req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/display.html')
} )

/*app.get('/page/:2',(req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/display.html')
} )*/

 
app.listen(8080)
```

`How can I do this in the backend using Node and express?

Answer (score 0):

Extract `pageNumber` from URL params by using `req.params`
This way you define a single route.

```js
app.get('/page/:pageNumber',(req, res) => {
  // Do something with the `pageNumber`
  const { pageNumber } = req.params;
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/display.html')
});
```